# ACPI conflicts with ACPI region SMRG

Tags: hardware, startup, acpi

During startup, I noticed some error. I found this in `dmesg`:

```
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: PCI INT B -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
ACPI: I/O resource 0000:00:1f.3 [0x400-0x41f] conflicts with ACPI region SMRG [0x400-0x40f]
ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

What does this mean? Which device is it talking about and how do I know which driver I should install?

Comment: Do you have any specific problem (e.g. system crashes, error messages)?

Comment: The only problem I have, is if the monitor goes to sleep, then it seem impossible to turn it back on, but I do not know if this problem is related to the error in `dmesg`.

Comment: I see no relation, but I might be wrong, esp. since SMbus (to which the first line of the message refers) can be used for power management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post in the Linux kernel mailing-list](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/5/31/404), it should not mean a problem:

> Unless you need to use anything on SMBus (hardware sensors, essentially) you don't have to worry about that one. It means that the kernel has  detected that the BIOS may potentially access the SMBus controller which may conflict with usage of the controller from within the OS.